# Registry - Create Key - Security

Tags: registry

I'm considering creating a key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  I've read the MDSN and kind of understand what to do but am concerned about the Registry Security business.  I want any user on the system to be able to access the key.  Do I need to specify something in the  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES parameter of the RegCreateKeyEx call?  If so what?  Under the description of that parameter, there is a link to SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES where it says "This is not the same as granting access to everyone by assigning a NULL discretionary access control list (DACL)." But I can't find out exactly what that means.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want any user to be able to read the key, or to write it? By default any user will be able to read the key without any additional effort on your part. If you want to specify additional security attributes such as write access then you will need to specify the security attributes.

I found an article here entitled [Creating a DACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717798(VS.85).aspx). Use the code in there, or some variant, and then do something like this:

```
 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  sa;

 sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
 sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;  

 // Call function to set the DACL. The DACL
 // is set in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES 
 // lpSecurityDescriptor member.
 if (!CreateMyDACL(&sa))
 {
     // Error encountered; generate message and exit.
     printf("Failed CreateMyDACL\n");
     exit(1);
 }

 RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &sa, &hKey, NULL);
```

Comment: Ok, that's helpful.  

Could someone supply code to establish a world write when creating the key?  Or point me at some similar example in the MDSN?  

I'm also curious as to what happens when a user removes some installed software; do any keys that software created get left behind as orphans?

Comment: Generally creation and deletion of registry keys and configuration is left up to the installation and removal routines in the software. It does not happen automatically.